# How to reset an array within a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services, wordpress

I work with a plugin within Wordpress which automatically imports info from amazon to be displayed as individual posts on my site. The plugin is designed to have a "campaign" for each search that it will run on amazon. The plugin has a built-in function that allows me to reset each campaign *individually* when it reaches to maximum pages in amazon. This allows the campaign to continue searching for products and creating posts.

The trouble is, I have over 1000 campaigns that need to be reset every few days. I'd like to set up a "Reset All" ability within the plugin. Here's what we have so far:

This is the function for actually resetting the value showing when the campaign was last run:

```
function ResetKeywordPages( $post_id )
{
    $custom = $this->get_post_custom( $post_id );
    $this->update_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_processed', time() );
    if( !$custom['amazon_product_keywords'] )
        return;
    $keyword_bits = array();
    if( $custom['amazon_product_keywords'] )
    {
        if( $custom['amazon_keyword_logic'] == 'and' )
            $keyword_bits[] = $custom['amazon_product_keywords'];
        else
            $keyword_bits = explode( ',', $custom['amazon_product_keywords'] );
    }
    else
    {
        $keyword_bits[] = 'empty'; // just so the logic works for category-only campaigns
    }
    foreach( $keyword_bits as $key => $value )
    {
        if( !is_array( $value ) )
            $value = trim( $value );
        if( !$value )
            continue;
        if( $value == 'empty' )
            $value = '';
        $node_string = $custom['amazon_product_node'];
        $search_hash = $this->SearchSlug( $value, $node_string );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_iter_'.$search_hash, 1 );
    }
}
```

This is the existing reset.php which completes the function for the defined 'item_id':

```
<?php require_once( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))))).'/wp-load.php' );
$response = array();
$item_id = $_GET['item_id'];
if( $item_id )
{
$qodys_pinner->PostType('amazon-campaign')->ResetKeywordPages( $item_id );

update_post_meta( $item_id, 'last_processed', 0 );
}
/*
$response['results'][] = 'Amazon campaign keyword pages reset successfully';
$qodys_pinner->Helper('postman')->SetMessage( $response );*/

$url = $qodys_pinner->Helper('tools')->GetPreviousPage();

header( "Location: ".$url );
exit;
?>
```

I'm still pretty new to PHP, so I'm at a loss when it comes to modifying arrays and other functions like this. I looked all over for something that would help me with this, but turned up nothing; I think it's because this plugin is pretty customized in the way it works?

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide! :)

-Chase

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find a way of listing all the "item_ids" for the campaigns you want to reset. Have a look at the code that generates the links to "reset.php", and see if it has a query that could help.

Once you have that, you just need a modified version of reset.php which loops over the item_ids rather than just picking up a single ID:

```
 require_once( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))))).'/wp-load.php' );
 $response = array();

 #TODO get $all_item_ids from somewhere...

 foreach ( $all_item_ids as $item_id )
 {
      $qodys_pinner->PostType('amazon-campaign')->ResetKeywordPages( $item_id );

      update_post_meta( $item_id, 'last_processed', 0 );
 }
 /*
 $response['results'][] = 'Amazon campaign keyword pages reset successfully';
 $qodys_pinner->Helper('postman')->SetMessage( $response );*/

 $url = $qodys_pinner->Helper('tools')->GetPreviousPage();

 header( "Location: ".$url );
 exit;
```

Comment: Hi IMSoP, thanks for your reply... The code that generates the links to reset.php simply puts the wordpress $post_id in for the $item_id. The code is: 
///////////////////////////////////////////
case "reset":
     echo '<a href="'.$this->GetAsset( 'forms', 'reset', 'url ').'?item_id='.$post_id.'">reset</a>';
     break;`
/////////////////////////////////////////////
 Do you know of a way to loop over the post_ids and put them in as the item id?

Thanks again for your help :)
-Chase